# Visual Studio Code (Python) - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I searched all the internet for a solution and didn't find it.

Well, i recently installed Anaconda Package, and the VS Code with all the required extensions, but like in every language i tried to run a:

```
print('Hello World')
```

But the code stopped with the following message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

[image: PrintScreen Error Msg]

Comment: Could be that `print` is leveraging `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdout` is somehow `None`

Comment: @C.Nivs and how could i solve this problem

Comment: it seems that vscode might be broken https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Visual Studio Code in the administrator mode solved that issue for me.